# Is "this->" always replaceable by explicit scope resolution in C++?

Tags: c++, this

Many programmers like to use `this->` (my feeling is that even if it is not necessary). Its advantage is obvious in class templates with base classes that depend on template parameters, and if templates has virtual functions it may be the only solution.

So my question is the following: not considering dependent templates is `this->` can always be either skipped or replaced by explicit scope resolution?

Comment: On the other hand, using scope resolution can be skipped in cases where you use this-> instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With name hiding, you have to use `this` when `virtual` comes into play:

```
struct Base
{
    virtual ~Base() = default;
    virtual void func() { std::cout << "Base\n"; }
    void foo(std::function<void()> func)
    {
        func();       // call the std::function
        this->func(); // virtual/dynamic call
        Base::func(); // static call
    }
};

struct Derived : Base
{
    virtual void func() { std::cout << "Derived\n"; }
};



int main()
{
    Derived d;

    d.foo([](){std::cout << "lambda\n";});
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a04a9ca5b52de8ec)

Comment: Setters(/constructors) might easily have name hiding, `void setX(int x) {this->x = x;}` (explicit scope might replace `this->` here though) (and for constructor, using member initializer lists avoids that need).

Comment: Yes, of course I know that setters can have name hiding, but I did not considered that it can be a function too.